# How can I set exceptions to the 'invert' property in css?

Tags: css, colors, inversion, adjustment

I want to invert colors via the css property 'invert' (for dark mode),
but at the same time I want to leave 5 specific color to stay the same,
and other 5 specific colors - not to invert, but to transform into specifically set 5 colors.
Images are also to be left untouched.
What code should be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't do so using **invert** css property.

**invert** takes **1** parameter which is the amount of inverse

invert(amount);

you can invert all  elements except some specific elements, but you can't specify this by color.

check [MDN invert() Specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert())

Comment: Thanks! 

Apart from 'invert', perhaps there's some other way to specify scopes of color hex-codes and a pattern on how to transform them into appropriate colors that look better on darker backgrounds; with the exception of specific colors that need to be specified particularly?

Comment: I don't know how you may implement such thing, even if you could it would be much harder than using two themes,  I think you should consider using two themes and activate each one using javascript, by giving the body a class of dark/light on a button click , and style it in css.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it would be the best way to stylize html where you know (or yourself set) the colors. But in this case, I'm intending to enhance dark theme for a free dictionary app which reads different formats of dictionaries and it's impossible to predict which colors were used in them. So I seek some automated way, and the invert function seems to be it. But at the same time, I need to leave untouched (or transform individually customized) the 5 colors that represent Chinese characters with different tones, hence the question